# Laravel 5.1 authentication use Pin to register users

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am creating website for a school and i am using laravel built in authentication to register new users, but i want add a field in the registration form  for scratch card pin so it checks the pin table whether the pin is used  or not.My problem is if create function inside authcontroller cant return a view.

So i got this error message

ErrorException in **Guard.php line 430**:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given

here is my authcontroller

```
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */


protected function create(array $data)
{

    $spin=$data['pin'];
    $pins = Pin::where('pin', $spin)
           ->get();

    if(  $pins[0]->status == 0)
    {      

    Pin::where('pin', $spin)
      ->update(['status' => 1]);  

      return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    }

    else{

    return redirect()->back();



    }
```

[This is my registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLdPI.jpg)

Comment: maybe consider marking the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are incorrectly modifying the protected `create()` method. See how the return response must always be `User` from the documented comments? You on the other hand, are sometimes returning a redirect response - hence the error message you are getting.

There is likely to be some laravel class somewhere trying to authenticate the user using the `create()` method. When it receives a `RedirectResponse` instance instead, it throws an error as it was expecting an instance of `User`

Don't return anything but `User` in the `create()` method

Comment: actually want it to return a reponse, as you can from the if statement, if the pin is not used then  create user function to run but if the pin is used, i want it to direct back with a message that the pin is used.

Comment: first of thank you quick replies, i am doing all things in authcontroller class which main purpose for authenticatn, i just add some if statement,if a certain condition is satisfied then create the user , but if not ,dont create the user and goback to registration

Comment: Try writing you code in this file: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php` inside `postRegister` method.

Comment: have just worked out you are modifying the standard laravel authcontroller, not one of your own. See updated answer